# Quickfix Field Tag is Invalid: 54

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, quickfix

Hello I am trying to use Quickfix with FIX 4.4 using a Python Wrapper for a personal resume builder. I have googled to all over for help with this but haven't found anything to figure this out.

So in Quickfix's Data Dictionary here:

```
field number='54' name='Side' type='CHAR'
```

It is telling us that this tag must be a CHAR.

However in our method to send an order looks like this:

```
    def sendOrder(self, tradeSide):
    print("Creating the following order: ")
    cTime = datetime.utcnow()
    qOrder = fix.Message()
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField( fix.BeginString("FIX.4.4") )
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField(35, "D" )       
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField(49, "Place_To_Go")
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField(56, "Place_To_Trade")
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField(43,"Y")
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.getHeader().setField(52, str(cTime))
    print(qOrder)

    qOrder.setField(40, chr(1) )
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(11, str(self.genOrderID()))
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(311, "EUR")
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(309, "EUR/USD.E.FX")
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(305, "111") 
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(54, chr(1))
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(60, str(cTime))
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(38, "1" )
    print(qOrder)
    qOrder.setField(59, "1" )

    print("Order:" + str(qOrder))
    print("ayyy")

    fix.Session_sendToTarget(qOrder)
```

You can see in this line:
    qOrder.setField(54, chr(1))

That we are trying to force it to become a char however when we send the message to the server we still recieve:

```
(Invalid message: Field tag is invalid: 54)
```

In a tester online our FIX message appears to be valid on this website:

http://fixparser.targetcompid.com?sharedlink=-LF0tkvCToW5RzneNJg2

Input this key:

```
jaiPj3brnf7tlgy5X28BgqwCwxpIq7H%BH6b81joE!rUzWof9hQvvby3
```

Does anyone have any experience in why it is still blatantly rejecting our message?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I know nothing of Python, but if CHAR(1) is actually ASCII code 1, this is the SOH character (Start Of Heading). That is not a valid value for tag 54. You want the character '1', not SOH.

Comment: Can you show us the message that is triggering this error?  (Actual FIX messages are the most important clue to solving any FIX issue.)

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Yes I if you go to the fixparser website and enter the key I've give you, it's the only way to accurately display the message for others. That way it breaks it down nicely. Thanks!

Comment: (Or you could have just pasted the message in your question....)  Yes, the message appears valid, and your message content disproves @TT's hypothesis.  I'm stumped.  I'd love to see the 35=3 or 35=j reject message as well.

Comment: I meant that I want to see the FIX message that contains `(Invalid message: Field tag is invalid: 54)`.  I'd prefer to see it with the D message that it applies to.

Comment: Understood thank you Grant. It is my fault but I believe we were able to identify the error and correct it and I will go back and find what our issue was so there is record of it on here. However, I was looking at an old post of yours for quickfix on our new error. Where tag 40 is out of range according to FIX. This page (http://quickfix.13857.n7.nabble.com/OrdType-out-of-range-for-a-NewOrder-Single-td1390.html). We are experiencing the same error except we are using FIX 4.4 already. Could you see anything wrong with that if I provided the message text for you again. Thank you!

Comment: @TT. You are correct that was the problem! I am not sure how to mark your answer as correct since you commented but I am crediting you and posting and answer to this. Thank you!

Comment: @smallKing I'll wrap it in an answer. Just check the checkmark next to it. And... you're welcome ;-)

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Just so you know I had forgotten to @ you in my last message and wanted to let you know I am still suffering from this issue whenever you have free time please contact me I'd appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CHAR(1)` is actually ASCII code 1, this is the `SOH` character (Start Of Heading). That is not a valid value for tag 54. You want the character `1`, not SOH.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your hypothesis in the comments above.  Now I see it.  Nice.